# Symlink still points to old version of AppImage

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, ubuntu-20.04, appimage

I have a script that autoupdates some AppImage applications and then it creates/updates a symlink with the new application (as they have a hash in their filename when they integrate, the previous symlink gets outdated).

```
$ ls -l ~/.bin/taskwarrior-tui
/home/user/.bin/taskwarrior-tui -> /home/user/Apps/taskwarrior-tui-$HASH.AppImage
```

But, if I execute the app from the symlink, the old version gets called.

```
$ ~/.bin/taskwarrior-tui --version
taskwarrior-tui 0.13.8

$ ~/Apps/taskwarrior-tui-$HASH.AppImage --version
taskwarrior-tui 0.13.10
```

So I see two problems: (1) I don't get how the symlink is pointing to an old version of (2) a software that supposedly I do not have "installed" anymore (i.e., the auto-update script removes the old AppImage). If I try to search for files related to the application on my filesystem with `locate` (after `updatedb`), only the newer version files appear, so there isn't any residual stuff on the filesystem at least.

I tried to strace the execution of both commands (~/.bin/taskwarrior-tui and ~/Apps/taskwarrior-tui-$HASH.AppImage), but I cannot (easily) find any pointers there.

Eventually (probably after a reboot) the problem solves, but still this shouldn't be happening. Whatever help you could give me to solve this will be appreciated.

**EDIT**:

Even weirder. If I am in the folder of the symbolic link, and execute it with the relative path, it calls the new version. If I execute it calling it from the full path, it executes the old version.

```
$ ~/.bin/taskwarrior-tui --version
taskwarrior-tui 0.13.8

$ ./taskwarrior-tui --version
taskwarrior-tui 0.13.10
```

**EDIT 2**:
Just in case, ~/.bin/ is also a symbolic link.

```
$ ls -l ~/.bin
/home/user/.bin -> /home/user/automation/bin/

$ ~/.bin/taskwarrior-tui --version
taskwarrior-tui 0.13.8

$ /home/user/automation/bin/taskwarrior-tui --version
taskwarrior-tui 0.13.10
```

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, that's the third command I showed. Directly executing the target of the symbolic link shows the new version (v0.13.10).

Comment: Just in case: what is the shell? Invoke `set -x`, then try all the commands again. Do commands that print `0.13.8` reveal something unexpected in the diagnostic output from the shell? Note: `set -x` can be reverted by `set +x`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I am using zsh but I just spawned a bash shell and tried the commands and the version difference still occurs. I checked the diagnostic output but didn't see anything particular, they are similar for the different commands (the lines that differ are, of course, the command that was executed).